# Make Firefox auto-redirect to mobile sites

Tags: firefox

I need to make Firefox automatically redirect me to mobile-friendly versions of some sites (e.g. BBC, Engadget) whenever I click a link to the desktop version. I have to do this to reduce my Internet bills when traveling overseas.

I tried changing the user agent string to that of the iPhone's, Nokia's Webkit, Opera Mobile, etc but found that some web sites don't automatically redirect me to their mobile sites.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the Firefox [Redirector addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirector/) to manually define each URL you want to redirect. Each URL can then redirect you to the mobile version of the site.

You may also need [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) to handle the mobile requests.