# How can I Use Google Search mobile version in desktop browsers?

Tags: browser, google-search

As you're all know there are different version of Google Search is available respective to your client device (Mobile/Desktop). Since, Mobile version uses less bandwidth I was trying to access the Mobile version in Desktop browser. But whenever I access the [mobile version URL](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=germany&oq=germany%20v&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j5j0.17914j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8) in desktop browser, It's just getting redirected to desktop version itself.

If I use facebook mobile site URL, [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com/) I'm still able to access the same in desktop browsers as well. It's getting loaded very fast & uses less bandwidth.

So is there any way I can force to use mobile version of Google search in desktop browsers? This will save alot bandwidth and load faster as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browse Mobile Websites From Desktop/Laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/11321/browse-mobile-websites-from-desktop-laptop), [Make Firefox auto-redirect to mobile sites](http://superuser.com/questions/299484/make-firefox-auto-redirect-to-mobile-sites) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a extension named **User Agent Switcher** available for both Google-Chrome and Mozilla-Firefox.Here is the link for its chrome extension:

[User-Agent-Switcher-for-chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US)

Install this extension and restart your web browser.

After that an icon will appear on the right-top corner of your browser. Click on that icon and select `Android`.

Then open any web-page you want. Now you will be able to access all the mobile version websites

If you want to have same feature enabled in Firefox, then follow the link given below:

[User-Agent-Switcher-for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

Install the plug-in and Restart your browser. Click on the **Open Menu** button on the right-top corner and then select **Customize**.

Add the plug-in button on your toolbar. Use iOS option. And Firefox is enabled to open mobile version url.

Comment: Can you clarify, on a desktop, what are the ramifications of selecting Android or iOS?  Does this affect the UI, or is this a nonsense selection that doesn't affect anything?

Comment: Jenson 's query was "how to access mobile version website in a Desktop Browser". and my answer can exactly be used for that purpose.

Comment: My question was only about selecting Android vs. iOS as part of implementing your solution.  Neither is present on a desktop PC, so I'm trying to understand what "whichever you prefer" means.  Are these settings to select a preferred display format / user interface, or is this essentially an irrelevant setting and it makes no difference what you select?  Thanks.

Comment: @Hunter: Can you link to the Firefox version too, since you've mentioned that browser as well? Also why is the add-on name in ALL CAPS? The answer is sound though.

Comment: @Karan I have added link to the firefox version. and also removed ALL CAPS.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually i am also unaware of the difference between android mode and iOS mode. So I have removed that section of my answer. I'll learn more about it and then try to get back to you on this topic

Comment: @Hunter: Well done, upvoted. :)